# MongoDB Performance when connecting to multiple databases via parent-child connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

When connecting to a mongo server containing multiple dbs, what is more performant approach using node-mongodb-native driver.

Let's say I have 8 dbs(db1...db8) on the same Mongo Server. My node app needs to connect to all 8 depending on the queries received to it. What is a better option here for me

1) Create 8 separate connections  (1 with each db)

OR

2) Create one parent connection to the server on test db and then call db.db 8 times to create 8 child connections under that parent. As I read in the doc(http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#db), all 8 child connections will be running on the same socket

Has anyone researched into this or has some background or thoughts that can help me determine the right course of action?

Answer (score 1):

1. *How granular is MongoDB concurrency?*: this depends on the version. Since MongoDB 3 many operations lock on the document. Earlier versions would apply a lock on the entire collection. Some operations still lock on the entire *instance* (aka server). This means that sometimes an operation (likely operations involving multiple databases) can block an entire instance affecting all databases within it. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb
2. *Threading model*: node.js is asynchronous while MongoDB is not. MongoDB will use one thread per socket. If you perceive operations are blocking each other you should keep seperate connection pools. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/faq/